# Angular binding @input behavior not working propertly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, binding

I'm having some issues with the Angular `EventEmitter` and angular `@Input`.

My app has 3 components: 2 components (`TableComponent` and `MapComponent`) that do not interact between them, and an extra component that is like the father of those two (`BodyComponent`).

`TableComponent` defines the following @Input

```
  _oportunidades: Item[];
  @Input() set oportunidades(oportunidades: Item[]){
    debugger;
    this._oportunidades = oportunidades;
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Item>(this._oportunidades);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
```

The `MapComponent` defines:

```
 @Output() event_emitter_for_items_filtered_by_polygon = new EventEmitter<string[]>();
  send_new_map_information_to_body(){
    this.event_emitter_for_items_filtered_by_polygon.emit(this.items_filtered_by_polygon);
  }

  add_function_that_sends_filtered_items_to_body_after_polygon_is_draw(){
    var self = this;
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
      self.filter_items_by_polygon(polygon);
      self.remove_markers_from_map();
      polygon.setPath([])
      self.send_new_map_information_to_body();
    });
  }
```

When the procedure `send_new_map_information_to_body` is triggered. Sends the modified data to the `BodyComponent`. The `BodyComponent` catches it **without errors**.
The `BodyComponent` html is shown here:

```
<div class="analysis">
  <app-mapa (event_emitter_for_items_filtered_by_polygon)="items_filtered_by_polygon($event)" [items]="map_data"></app-mapa>
  <app-tabla [oportunidades]="oportunidades_filtradas"></app-tabla>
</div>
```

The procedure `items_filtered_by_polygon` modifies the `oportunidades_filtradas` variable defined in the `BodyComponent`. Until now, everything is ok.

```
  items_filtered_by_polygon($event){
    this.oportunidades_filtradas = []
  }
```

The variable `oportunidades_filtradas` is binded to the `oportunidades` variable in the `TableComponent` (as shown in the `BodyComponent` html), when `items_filtered_by_polygon` method changes `oportunidades_filtradas` the `@Input() set oportunidades(oportunidades: Item[])` is not triggered. So, no changes are shown in my `TableComponent`.

When the app starts, and data is distributed through the components, everything works as expected. Just in this case, when trying to modify the `TableComponent` content as explained, nothing happens.

In the devtools console of chrome, no errors are shown. And the flow of the app does not feel strange, just nothing happens. 
Sometimes, we thought that the modifications are being done, but maybe they are terrible delayed? Maybe is some kind of async issue?

I'm kind of new in Angular and maybe I am not understanding something. All other binds in my app are working...

What do you think? Any help is welcome! 
Thanks!

Comment: Do you use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in BodyComponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like there may be a change detection issue happening. Depending on your change detection strategy things like this can happen. Try using [ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#!#detectChanges-anchor) in your items_filtered_by_polygon function to see if that's the issue. If it works you can leave it there or remove it and use an observable for the input that isn't triggering.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks for the advises. Reading about this solutions was really helpful in general.